# How do I set up a continuous deployment to an Azure Virtual Machine using Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-virtual-machine

I am trying to set up a continuous deployment using Azure Devops for my node.js project to a Linux Azure VM. Where do I find the deployment folder? I cannot find a decent documentation.

For the moment I set up a remote git server and deploy directly but it is not ideal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Azure DevOps, we can set up Continuous Integration and Continuous Deployment (CI / CD) of our web app to a Virtual Machine (Linux / Windows)

**Create Environment with virtual machines**:

1. Sign into your Azure DevOps organization and navigate to your project.
2. Navigate to the Pipelines page. Select Environments and click Create Environment. Specify a Name (required) for the environment and a Description.
3. Choose Virtual Machines as a Resource to be added to the environment. Click Next.
4. Choose Linux for the Operating System and copy the registration script.
5. Run the copied registration script in the VM

**Define your CI (build) pipeline to build your web app code and publish it to artifact**

**Define your CD (release) pipeline to deploy your web app to the Linux VM**

**Reference** : [Deploy to a Linux VM - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/ecosystems/deploy-linux-vm?view=azure-devops&tabs=javascript)